# Genesis allocation and (address, balance) tuples

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, genesis

On go-ethereum souce code at core\genesis_alloc.go(19):

```
...
package core

// Constants containing the genesis allocation of built-in genesis blocks.
// Their content is an RLP-encoded list of (address, balance) tuples.
// Use mkalloc.go to create/update them.

// nolint: misspell
const mainnetAllocData = "\xfa\x04]X\u0793\r..."
const testnetAllocData = "\xf9\x03\xa4\u0080..."
const rinkebyAllocData = "\xf9\x03\xb7\u0080..."
const goerliAllocData = "\xf9\x04\x06\u0080..."
```

what are all these? pre-funded wallets? I thought pre-funded wallets were specified on genesis block like this:

```
"alloc": {"2sa2a321h8353vba12as8965r3340huk3s6a2h6e": { "balance": "10" }, ...
```

where can I find the code that implements the call to AddBalance() for genesis block allocation? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought pre-funded wallets were specified on genesis block like this:...

I'm not certain (and someone can correct me), but I was always under the impression that each time you start a new Geth client from scratch, it generates itself the both the genesis block and genesis file from the data you've pointed to. (i.e. You won't find the `genesis.json` file in the `go-ethereum` repository as it doesn't exist until it's generated.)

> where can I find the code that implements the call to AddBalance() for genesis block allocation?

You want the [`ToBlock()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/72b21db2d31d77d956c09353457a0c2db45249b0/core/genesis.go#L229) function in `genesis.go`.